# running a mysql foreach with an array of values not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array with values like "849" and "584" or "275" etc and am running a mySQL query against each of these values. It appears to execute fine but I receive no values returned. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$content = "";
        foreach ($cookies_array as $key => $value){
            $sql_select_recent_items = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM products WHERE id=".$key." LIMIT 0,10");

            $content .="".$sql_recent_activity_items["id"]." - ".$sql_recent_activity_items["name"]."<br>";

        }
```

When I do a var_dump on the array, it shows correctly like:

```
array(10) { [0]=> string(3) "852" [1]=> string(3) "856" [2]=> string(3) "720" [3]=> string(3) "783" [4]=> string(3) "784" [5]=> string(3) "785" [6]=> string(3) "708" [7]=> string(3) "716" [8]=> string(3) "717" [9]=> string(3) "749" }
```

Comment: don't you want where id = $value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using either Mysqli or PDO as the $db.

In both case the result of query() does return a "result class" where you need to fetch the value. It doesn't return a simple array containing your result.

Mysqli fetch: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

(There are exemples so it quite easy ;))

So using Mysqli here a sample of what should work:

```
$content = "";
        foreach ($cookies_array as $key => $value)
        {
            $result = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM products WHERE id=".$value." LIMIT 0,10");
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                $content .="".$row["id"]." - ".$row["name"]."<br>";
            }
        }
```

NOTE1: I don't check for error, from documentation $result should be FALSE in those case.
NOTE2: You MUST sanitize any parameter you append to your query ESPECIALLY if it come from the client. (A cookie is on the client part).
Instead of

```
"SELECT id, name FROM products WHERE id=".$value." LIMIT 0,10"
```

it should look like

```
"SELECT id, name FROM products WHERE id=".$db->real_escape_string($value)." LIMIT 0,10"
```

NOTE3: I also recommand to batch your query for performance, you could use prepared statement ( http:// php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and use bind_param as the sanitize your value 
or have multiple OR condition in your WHERE)

NOTE4: I use $value in your query instead of $key because like other told you, $key is an index ("unique value" to get back the value from your array)

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$sql_select_recent_items = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM products WHERE id=".$key." LIMIT 0,10");`

to

`$sql_select_recent_items = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM products WHERE id=".$value." LIMIT 0,10");`

`$key` is the index whereas `$value` is the actual data on that index.